# Removing row of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Assuming I have a tensor k

```
    k=tf.random.normal([4,5],0,1)
    def sample_without_replacement(logits, K):
        """
        Courtesy of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9260#issuecomment-437875125
        """
        logits=tf.transpose(logits)
        z = -tf.math.log(-tf.math.log(tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(logits),0,1)))
        _, indices = tf.math.top_k(logits, K)
        return indices
indices=sample_without_replacement(k, 2):
k.remove(x,indices_of_size_two)#
```

Which function can i
use in place of '**remove**' to remove rows contained in indices from k ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a specific row from a tensor by using np.delete(). For example, if i have to remove the 1st row from a tensor k

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.02622163, -1.2923028 ,  3.2072415 ,  1.2431644 , -0.11518966],
       [ 1.2594987 , -1.6813043 , -0.4560027 ,  1.4999349 , -0.7349123 ],
       [ 0.21005473,  1.1832136 , -2.4060364 , -0.59930867, -0.1646447 ],
       [ 0.7740495 ,  0.48236254,  0.682837  , -0.54411227,  1.0912068 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

np.delete(k, obj=1, axis=0)

output:

```
array([[-0.02622163, -1.2923028 ,  3.2072415 ,  1.2431644 , -0.11518966],
       [ 0.21005473,  1.1832136 , -2.4060364 , -0.59930867, -0.1646447 ],
       [ 0.7740495 ,  0.48236254,  0.682837  , -0.54411227,  1.0912068 ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Thank You.